Embedding icon for Windows OS taskbar in executable made using pyinstaller on a tkinter script
I am using Windows 11 home OS , Python 3.11.9 and pyinstaller 6.11.1.
Here is my basic tkinter script (let us call it my-script.py):
import tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title:str="Simple", x:int=0, y:int=0, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title(title)
        self.config(**kwargs)
        self.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
        self.first_row_frame=tk.Frame(self)
        self.first_row_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='W')
        self.lbl_ser_num=tk.Label(self.first_row_frame,text="Sr No:",font='Arial 50 bold')
        self.lbl_ser_num.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.state('zoomed')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # height of 0 defaults to screenheight, else use height
    Application(title="simple app").mainloop()

As you can see, I used icon.ico for the icon (I cannot upload that file in this post, you can take one from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shanet/Cryptully/refs/heads/master/src/images/icon.ico).
I created an executable using this command:
pyinstaller --onefile -i "icon.ico" my-script.py 

This creates a dist folder that contains my-script.exe.
If I run my-script.exe, then I get following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "full-path-to-my-script.py", line 17, in 
Application(title="simple app").mainloop()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "full-path-to-my-script.py", line 7, in init
self.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
File "tkinter_init_.py", line 2155, in wm_iconbitmap
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon.ico" not defined
[PYI-2628:ERROR] Failed to execute script 'my-script' due to unhandled exception!

If I copy icon.ico to this dist folder, then the executable works as desired (icon is present in window title bar as well as taskbar).
My aim is to have a single .exe file to run the script. What am I doing wrong here?
Please let me know if any other detail is required.
Thanks
PS: I noticed that icon appears in Windows explorer file manager which is ok, but my target is big icon in taskbar when I run the .exe file.

Take a look on Runtime Information.

acw1668 , please see my answer and provide suggestion for sharp icon or code improvement . Thanks .

@acw1668 told to read https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html
Using that, I changed tkinter code to following
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from os import path
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title:str="Simple", x:int=0, y:int=0, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title(title)
        self.config(**kwargs)
        #
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            print('running in a PyInstaller bundle')
        else:
            print('running in a normal Python process')
        self.first_row_frame=tk.Frame(self)
        path_to_dat = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__),'icofolder'))
        print(path_to_dat)
        self.iconbitmap(path_to_dat+'\\icon.ico')
        self.first_row_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='W')
        self.lbl_ser_num=tk.Label(self.first_row_frame,text="Sr No:",font='Arial 50 bold')
        self.lbl_ser_num.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.state('zoomed')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # height of 0 defaults to screenheight, else use height
    Application(title="simple app").mainloop()

Then I created exe using following command
pyinstaller --clean --onefile -i "icon.ico" --add-data "icon.ico;icofolder" my-script.py

Then you simply run exe file of dist folder from anywhere.
Now only thing is that icon is blurry though my icon is 184x256 pixel as per mspaint.
